# How do I ignore timeouts in erlang?

Tags: erlang, deadlock

I have a server with a number of clients and each client is able to ask the server for information about the other clients. If they do so, the server have to get the information from each client and then return it to the asking client.

If two clients does this request at the same time, a deadlock might appear. The thing is that this request is done so often that the client would not have to care if it sometimes fails. How do I just ignore the timeout message that terminates everything when this problem appear?

Comment: Do you need synchronous calls to achieve what you are trying to do? Maybe your implementation would be easier if you used asynchronous messages. As for ignoring stuff in Erlang: If the crashing behaviour bothers you, check out `try..catch`. It's usually not what one wants to do, but often gets the job done. Note that a proper system design might still be a better option.

Comment: I would look at doing it asynchronously as well. Definitely the easiest way to avoid deadlocks. Though I will admit it is a different style of communication which can seem strange until you get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Strict answer to your question

If you're using gen_server, then [`call/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-3) allows you to specify a timeout (and `call/2` defaults to 5 seconds).

This code will either give you the gen_server's reply or the atom `timeout` if it failed.

```
Result = try gen_server:call(Target, Message, Timeout) of
             Reply ->
                 Reply
         catch
             exit:{timeout, _} ->
                 timeout
         end.
```

### Better answer

evnu and rvirding recommended using asynchronous calls, which is a superior technique. Here are two possible ways to do this:

#### 1. Server stores the data

Have clients periodically `gen_server:cast/2` to the server to tell it their information. The server stores the latest information about each client. When a client wants to learn about its siblings, it calls `gen_server:call/2` to the server.

The server call is synchronous because it doesn't need to contact any client; it's just returning the cached values.

#### 2. Async return

The clients call `gen_server:cast/2` to request data from the server. The server calls `gen_server:call/2` to fetch data from each client on demand. Once the server has collected all data, it calls `gen_server:cast/2` to pass the collected data back to the client that requested it.

Here, the clients are always waiting to handle requests from the server. The server calls the client synchronously, but can't deadlock because there is only one server.

#### 3. More gen_servers

This one's hard to describe without knowing more about your code, but you could break the clients into more pieces. One piece to handle data requests and another piece to generate the requests.

---

Based on your description that the clients make this data request "so often", I think you should try the first method. If your clients are requesting data frequently enough, having the server collect and cache the client information will actually result in fresher data for the clients.